# How can I increment the class names using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I set up an ng-repeat to rollout a bunch of elements from a JSON file however I would like each element to have a incremental class name .item-1, .item-2, .item-3.

```
<div ng-controller="itemCtrl">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span class="item-{{ item.length }}"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to add the number to `class="item-{{ item.length}}"` but I can't seem to get this working.

Comment: Have you checked the docs? https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what is the benefit of generating dynamic class names like this. A class should mean **a class of similar objects**.

It's still possible with `$index`:

```
<div ng-controller="itemCtrl">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span class="item-{{ $index }}"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 3):

As documented on https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat just use `$index`

```
<div ng-controller="itemCtrl">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span class="item-{{ $index }}"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 4 secs faster than @Khanh TO ;)

Comment: Cool, I had tried something similar but I didn't quite have it right. The class name starts at 'item-0' is it possible to make it start at 'item-1'?

Comment: @Daimz: just use `item-{{ $index + 1 }}`